# Ziggy error: 'query' parameter is required for route 'permission.search' , Laravel Inertia React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

My goal is to complete the search feature in my app then I'm facing a problem when sending data/query/keyword as a parameter to backend via Inertia request using **get** method. this is my first time using react and inertia so i don't have any idea to solve this.

error messege

> Ziggy error: 'query' parameter is required for route
> 'permission.search'

what my code looks like

```
import React, { useEffect , useState } from 'react';
import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout';
import InputLabel from '@/Components/InputLabel';
import { Head, Link, useForm, Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';

export default function Permission (props){
const { data, setData, get, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
    name: '',
});

const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

const submitQuery = () => {
    const keyword = {query}
    get(route('permission.search'),query) //try to passing data to controller
};


return (
    <AuthenticatedLayout auth={props.auth} errors={props.errors}>

        <div>                 
            <InputLabel forInput="query" value="Search" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Kategori" className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full" onChange={(query) => setQuery(query.target.value)} value={query} />

            <button className='btn btn-primary m-2' onClick={() => submitQuery()}>SUBMIT</button>
        </div>

    </AuthenticatedLayout>
    
)
}
```

and this my route looks like

```
Route::get('/permission/search/{query}', [\App\Http\Controllers\PermissionController::class, 'search'])->middleware(['auth','verified'])->name('permission.search');
```

this is my controller , only try to die dump the data

```
public function search($keyword){
    dd($keyword);
}
```

please help me to figure this out, Thank you in advance

Comment: you got a typo - `get(route('permission.search'),query)` to `get(route('permission.search', query))`

Comment: what a stupid mistake ... I trying to solve this for about a hour .. Thankyou bro @ericmp